# Messaging problems

Tags: php

I am creating a messaging system but the problem I face is that when users try and enter certain characters like ' into the message, the database doesnt want to allow it.
Any idea what this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called SQL injection. Basically, by not handling your user input properly, you're allowing anyone and everyone to execute arbitrary SQL statements (not good!). If you search for 'SQL Injection', you'll get *tonnes* of resources.

For starters, have a look at this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I know about SQL injection but i'm unaware how to allow the users to enter messages with such characters. mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: @Luke That's one solution. The question I linked to has some really good answers that outline other possibilities.

Comment: @Luke while "SQL inection" is terrible term to describe your problem, the solution is the same

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - Why's it a terrible term? If the DB is throwing errors when the user inputs `'` then it's almost certainly a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: I have looked at the solutions you provided. Thanks

Comment: "SQL injection" stands for "SQL injection attack", not "SQL injection vulnerability". And it's not actually a vulnerability but just malformed query.

Answer (score 0):

Make your SQL queries by using [PDO](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and not by munging strings.